# как узнать адрес радио потока

Tags: html, websocket

Как узнать адрес радио потока, чтобы можно было слушать потом в winamp. Просмотр кода страницы не помог, ProcessHacker тоже не помог

http://www.bbz.ru/bbzradio/

Comment: Немного покопав, вот что выяснил: Воспроизведение на себя берет плагин [SHOUTcast DNAS v2 via JSON-P](https://github.com/Wavestreaming/jquery-shoutcast) и вот некоторые данные с него: `host: "majestic.wavestreamer.com", playedInterval: 30000, port: 2293, statsInterval: 5000, stream:1`, [хотите слушать SHOUTcast DSP в Winamp?](http://www.shoutcast.com/Winamp), сейчас еще покопаю, что да как...

Comment: http://majestic.wavestreamer.com:2293 - так не работает

Comment: В общем, дело тёмное, брось ты эту затею...